# Partial string slice (or string split?) in new column

Tags: python, string, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to remove a word from a group of words in a column and insert that removed word into a new column. I figured out how to remove a part of a column and insert it into a new row, but I cannot figure out how to target a specific word (by placement I assume; "Mr." is always the 2nd word; or maybe by taking the word between the first "," and ".'s which is also always constant in my data set).

```
Name             Age  New_Name
Doe, Mr. John     23     Mr.
Anna, Mrs. Fox    33     Mrs.
```

EDITED the above to add another row

How would I remove the "Mr." from the name column and insert it into the "New_Name" column?

So far I have come up with:

```
data['New_name'] = data.Name.str[:2]
```

This doesn't allow me to specifically target "Mr." though.

I think I have to use a string.split, but the exact code is eluding me.

Answer (score 2):

If the Mr. is always in the same position as indicated by your example, this can be accomplished with list interpolation:

```
df['New_Name'] = [x.split(' ')[1] for x in df['Name']]
```

and

```
d['Name'] = [' '.join(x.split(' ')[::2]) for x in d['Name']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = "Doe, Mr. John"

# if you always expect a title (Mr/Ms) between comma and dot
# split to lastname, title and firstname and strip spaces
newname = [ n.strip() for n in name.replace(".", ",").split(",") ]

print(newname)
#> ['Doe', 'Mr', 'John']
```

then you can print a title and a firstname-lastname column or other combination of them.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to get title from a name (it is between comma and dot) and stores it to another column. Then repeat this operation to remove title from column 'Name':

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Doe, Mr. John', 'Anna, Ms. Fox'], 'Age':[23,33]})
df['New_Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x[x.find(',')+len(','):x.rfind('.')]+'.')
df['Name'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(x[x.find(',')+len(','):x.rfind('.')]+'.',''))
print df
```

Output:

```
   Age       Name New_Name
0   23  Doe, John      Mr.
1   33  Anna, Fox      Ms.
```

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, I am not sure what was going on but now it works. Thanks again!

Comment: My code works only if a title is situated between comma and dot. It there is no comma and / or dot it will return `NaN`. Between comma and dot may be any type of words: Mr, Miss, Master, Mistress etc. Code just tries to find a word between comma and dot.

Comment: It works great! Now I am just trying to figure out how the code is working. I've never used lambda, len, or rfind. I just started learning python and this problem is leaps and bounds ahead of anything I've seen so far. I am not sure if this is appropriate, but could you summarize what is going on? I am researching the functions you used but am having trouble figuring out how they all fit together. If not that is ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: First it is find a comma in string then from the position of comma to the right the dot is find and the text between comma and dot is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas str.replace and str.extract methods

First extract title to form new column

```
df['New_Name'] = df['Name'].str.extract(',\s([A-Za-z]+.)')
```

Then use replace to replace extracted string with empty string

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace('\s([A-Za-z]+.)\s', ' ')
```

You get:

```
    Age Name        New_Name
0   23  Doe, John   Mr.
```